# OctoberCms - Model Filter Field Depends on Filter Field

Tags: model, builder, octobercms

I have a filtered field depending on a filtered field:
...

```
basket:
    label: Basket
    prompt: 'Add Item'
    span: full
    type: repeater
    form:
        fields:
            item:
                label: Item
                emptyOption: 'Select Product'
                showSearch: true
                span: auto
                type: dropdown
            totalprice:
                label: 'Total Price'
                span: right
                readOnly: 1
                dependsOn:
                    - item
                type: number

subtotal:
    label: 'Sub Total'
    span: auto
    default: ''
    readOnly: 1
    dependsOn:
        - basket
    type: number
```

The idea is that when an item within the basket is updated, the total price for that item updates which causes the basket to update. this then makes the subtotal for the basket update.

The total price for each item updates fine no issues at all. However, the subtotal seems to always be one update behind. I believe this is because the fields are only actually updates at the end of the filterfields function?

Is there anyway to allow filterfields dependant on filtered fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my experience repeater are a quick, but not the ideal solution for tasks as you are describing. A related 'basketitem' table with a *belongsTo* (baskitem *belongsTo* bask, bask *hasMany* baskitems) could solve your problem.
And by the way there is a tutorial to use as a pattern at https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-21

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials to deal with relations in OctoberCMS, on the october website as well as on YouTube from Ivan Doric (watch and learn). I also started to create a wiki where the relations *belongsTo* and *hasMany* are described in a step-by-step how-to. You will find it here, if you like: https://octobercms.wiki/doku.php#builder_by_example
As well as links to other tutorials, tips etc.